# Playing music on a website with PHP

Tags: php

So for my Garry's Mod server, I have a loading screen using my website. I only have an image currently, but I wan't to make it play a song while the user waits while loading. My plan is that I make a list of YouTube links, and the PHP coding picks a random link, and plays that song. I have no clue on how to use PHP except for variables.

Comment: How long is the loading time of your site that it needs a song on loading screen?

Comment: The loading time depends on the user, I just want a song to start playing, and when it finishes, it will play another random song on the list if they still are connecting.

Comment: so it takes more than 1 song before it loads? I think that's the bigger problem than adding a song. Anyways, this question is too broad for SO.

Comment: You might want want to research on how to `embed` youtube videos.  And you might want to check `rand()` function on php

Comment: Like I said, it depends on the user's computer. When I load into my server, it usually takes about 30 seconds, but for some players that have a poor computer/never have joined my server, it can take up to 5 or more.

Comment: And also, adding songs (youtube vid) will also add to loading time of your site.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I suggest to you one example. So, Try the code,

**Youtube URL look like this :** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWsqTrDJ_gU

The part you're going to want to copy is everything after the equals sign, or in the example above: yWsqTrDJ_gU

Copy on that text into a text file, hit Enter and paste everything after the equals sign of the URL on the next video page on the following line. You'll end up with a series of lines that look something like this:

- 5MQ0QX870FE
- yWsqTrDJ_gU
- JyTawuNvQi0
- HwRQ9dbti-4
- _ziv_WeBLvo

Save this text file with a meaningful name and upload it to your Web server. Next you need to build the code to display your video. If you copy the following and paste it onto a page that supports PHP, replacing only the **YourVideoList.txt** with the path to your file, you should get a YouTube player with a randomized set of videos.

```html
<?php

// Build an array from the list of YouTube videos
// Replace YourVideoList.txt with the path to your text file
// This will likely be something like /home/accountname/public_html/foldername/etc
$video_array = file('YourVideoList.txt');

// Randomly pick one video from the array
$video = $video_array[rand(0, count($video_array) - 1)];
$video = trim($video);

?>

<object width="425" height="350"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $video;? >"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $video;?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="350"></embed></object>
```

Note: Don't copy anything beyond this point for your code.

Hope! it's work for you!!

Comment: How will the OP stop the song after the site loads? How about the next song?

Comment: I think I copied something wrong, as now I get an HTTP error.

Comment: @That1nub - do you try this code or your own code??

Comment: This code. Like I stated in the question, I don't know PHP, so I couldn't have come up with another code